# Xcode 4.1 with more than 400 compiling errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Probably is a stupid thing but I'm quite new with Xcode... Today I've updated to OS X Lion and XCode 4.1 but now when I try to compile my iPhone app more than 400 compiling errors appear, some of them are even from sqlite3.h, CLLocation.h and other original libraries from Apple. All errors seem to be originated by a problem with `#import ...`

Yesterday I was working with OS X Snow Leopard with Xcode 4.0 and all was fine. I'm using GCC 4.2 compiler in Xcode and I haven't change any configuration on Xcode or my app.

Here are some errors:
http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/7585/screenshotyum.png

Help please!

UPDATE:
Ok, I solved the problem. It was not related with the compiler version or the base SDK, the error was that Xcode 4.1 doesn't accept the `#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"`, it has to be change to `#import <sqlite3.h>`

More info [here](http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/7585/screenshotyum.png) (only Apple Developers)

Hope this will help to other people.

Comment: I thought they dropped support for GCC in this version of Xcode... have you tried switching to the LVVM compiler?

Comment: Sometimes creating a new Xcode project and dropping all files into it does the trick. You'll also want to turn of automatic reference counting.

Comment: I have switched to LLVM 2.1 and now the build process return only one error but quite strange: in _sqlite3.h_ it says _Expected function body after function declarator_ for line: "SQLITE_API int sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_5_0);" But this is a system library... I've tried so set up severel iOS targets but the same...

Comment: Thanks for the find David, I was suffering with the exact symptoms...

Comment: You could upload pictures using Cmd+G.

Comment: You should answer your own question and close it for completeness.  It was helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: @ryyst - You need 4.2 for ARC, not 4.1

Comment: Hi David, I've got the similar error " Expected function body after function declarator" in Runtime.h because of upgrading Xcode 4.1 even after changed #import style.

Answer (score 3):

This caused me some serious headaches so thanks for posting! To clarify, after updating to Lion and Xcode 4.1 I had 400 errors because of: `#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"` but changing it to `#import <sqlite3.h>` solved it! Took me ages to figure this out!!!